# How to handle concurrency with StorageFile operations?

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I'm attempting to write to a file but "occasionally" I run into issues that I think are down to concurrency, as *some* of the time, I'm getting a `System.UnauthorizedAccessException` with message:

> Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

...from the following:

```
public async void SubmitChanges()
{
    DataContractSerializer serializer = 
        new DataContractSerializer(typeof(LocalCache<T>));

    StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder
            .CreateFileAsync(GetFileNameForType(), 
                CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

    //Occasionally throws here
    using (var fi = await file.OpenTransactedWriteAsync())
    {
        serializer.WriteObject(fi.Stream.AsStreamForWrite(), this);
        await fi.CommitAsync();
    }
}
```

I can only assume that this is down to some concurrency, or it being still open for read somewhere else, but I can't seem to find a way to wait for it to become available - I'd normally `lock` around it, but this is not allowed with `await` so what are the other options?

Comment: If it is a concurrency issue and you need to lock could you possibly use SemaphoreSlim.WaitAsync()  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh462788.aspx

Comment: @mydogisbox This code is for *saving*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually, you just don't start the next operation until the previous operation is complete.

Tip: avoid `async void`; use `async Task` instead. That enables you to know when the previous operation is complete.

Comment: I'd been staring at this for quite a while, and completely missed that - been a loooong day, cheers :)

Comment: FYI, there *is* an `AsyncLock` [developed by Stephen Toub](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/02/12/10266988.aspx) and available in [AsyncEx](http://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com/). I just didn't feel it was needed in this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of things that could be happening here. As Stephen mentioned above, your encapsulating method does not return a task. This means that whatever method is calling **SubmitChanges** is calling it with a "fire and forget" pattern and code that follows this call can be run in parallel. This is probably *not* what you want.

In addition, I notice you're using **StorageFile.OpenTransacted**. I've not used this before but the notes indicate OpenTransacted is only supported on operating systems that support [ReplaceFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/aa365512.aspx). This feature literally allows the new file to assume the identity of the old file, but I'm pretty sure that operation would fail if the old file is open.

I don't think the attempt to swap file identities would happen until the transacted file is closed, which would happen on **Dispose**, which happens automatically due to the **using** statement, which is the line you're sometimes seeing the exception.

I would recommend you return a Task instead and I would also consider using the regular **StorageFile.OpenAsync**.

Comment: I'm using `OpenTransacted` to avoid a read finding a half baked copy of the file - I perhaps need to think about my object life cycle, as it may be a touch IO intensive at the moment...