# File contents lost/corrupted when using StorageFile

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-8.1-universal, storagefile

TL/DR: We have a Windows Universal Application which interacts with JSON data stored locally using the StorageFile class. After using the app for a day, the user gets an UnauthorizedAccessException and the data disappears.

Long version: We have a Windows Universal Application which retrieves data from an API and saves that data locally to JSON files in the ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder for our app so the users can work offline. The data is typically retrieved at the start of the day and at the end of the day sent back to the API. When a record is successfully sent back to the API it is removed from the local JSON. The entire sync process with the API is manually triggered using a button in the UI. This workflow also limits the amount of data being sent between the app and the API and prevents the local files from growing endlessly.

We load data into in-memory collections by using the StorageFile class to read the contents of the JSON file and converting them to our model objects using the Newtonsoft JsonConvert object. All of this has been cruising along smoothly for some time until recently, when the users started reporting that data was disappearing. Looking at the log files for the apps, we are seeing one consistent error pop up:

```
'Exception when reading file "<filename>" from storage: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
at HQSTouch.Infrastructure.StorageManager.<ReadFromStorageAysnc>d__2.MoveNext()'
```

We may see this error when reading the file or when writing to it. The unfortunate result of these errors, at least from the perspective of the end users, is that the data disappears. This typically happens after the user has been using the app for most of the day, completing their work on says 10 out of 15 records. In my testing I've seen the JSON file size jump from <50Kb to as high as a couple hundred Kb, which didn't seem too excessive.

Now when the data disappears, it doesn't all disappear. After the file access error, if the user was still working on a record so it is in memory, that one record ends up being the only record in the local JSON file. When saving the data to the local file, we load up the data from the file into a collection, merge in the modified record, then serialize and write it all back out to the JSON file, replacing the contents of the file.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Edit: while this may be similar to the questions posted in [How to handle concurrency with StorageFile operations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12697178/how-to-handle-concurrency-with-storagefile-operations), we've been cautious with our async/await operations especially when interacting with the file system. Quick scan of the code stack show that our methods return a Task and are awaited. I feel our situation is different that what was discussed in that thread. For one user in particular this issue just started happening after the latest round of Windows updates. Prior to the Windows updates they had been using the application for some time without any issues. There were not any updates to our app in that time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle concurrency with StorageFile operations?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12697178/how-to-handle-concurrency-with-storagefile-operations)

Comment: While we do make use of async/await, all methods return Task and are awaited throughout the code stack when reading from or writing to the files.